# How to fix a remote branch on Git ahead of my local repository without doing a pull

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I am working on a project with a number of people using git.  I am remote from the team, and the way we have worked is like so:

1) they create branches off 'develop', then merge them into 'develop' after testing and push that to the origin repo.  This happens a lot.

2) I, every so often, create my own develop branch off the origin: a branch called 'my_develop'.  I then create branches off that, test them and merge them into 'my_develop'.

3) as they update 'develop', I frequently merger 'develop' INTO my branch (i.e., into my_develop).  This minimizes divergence without needing to integrate my work into develop on a daily basis.

4) about once a month, I push 'my_develop' to origin, issue a pull request, and it gets merged into develop - and then I start with a new 'my_develop2', etc.

Here is the problem.  In a nutshell, at one point, code got into develop that had some serious problems that went undetected for a short while.  I had, however, merged this bad 'develop' branch into 'my_develop', and pushed it to origin.  It became a functionality problem that froze my progress, so I at one point, on my local repository, done a 'git reset' to a commit on 'my_develop' three commits prior to what is on origin.

The problem now is that I can't push 'my_develop' to origin.  It objects on the grounds that the 'tip' on origin is a few commits ahead of what I have locally, and asks me to do a pull to integrate the changes from origin on branch 'my_develop'.

The point, of course, is that I have been doing incremental development from that point a few commits back from what is on origin.  At this point, the HEAD of 'my_develop' on origin is outdated and a pull would undo all the changes I have made on the 'live' branch locally.

I have seen people make 3 suggestions how to fix this:

1) do a 'git push origin my_develop --force'.  Logically this is what I want to do, but there are many warnings about the dangers of doing this.

2) some suggestions say to handle this with a rebase, though I don't quite see how to do that.

3) option #3 involves using 'ours' as a means of merging but giving git guidance to decide which line of code 'wins' in a merge conflict.

Any advice on the best way to do this?

NOTE: I am the only person who does work on 'my_develop', if that helps.

NOTE since I first posted:  I suppose I could simply go onto my branch ('git checkout my_branch'), then create a new branch off that ('git checkout -b my_latest_branch'), and then simply work from that one - and then push that to origin and issue a pull request.  This would orphan the tip of 'my_branch', but do I care?

Comment: Option #4: Figure out what changes you've made, pull down the latest repo and integrate your changes.

Comment: even if I am the only one who uses this branch?  Really, what I want to do is pretend I never made those 3 commits and pushes.  Doing what you say will be a fair amount of work now.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you said you were using this Git repo along with others.  If you're not sharing this repo, you can pretty much do whatever is easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Because you're only one on `my_develop`

> NOTE: I am the only person who does work on 'my_develop', if that helps.

## I recommend git push with force option.

1. If you're only one on `my_develop` you can push with a force option like `git push origin my_develop --force'`. it's not effect to your team.
2. `rebase` is a good practice to update code from main branch into your feature brach(`my_develop`). but your branch **must never** merge anything before.
3. If code on `develop` is unstable, don't merge into your feature branch.

ps. you can create a new branch at the last commit before merge from develop and work on that.